# committing frame position changes for UITextView

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a UITextview which is below 2 UITextFields and a UISwitch.

If the UISwitch is on, I want to remove the 2 UITextFields and shift the UITextView up. If the UISwitch is toggled off again then I want the 2 UITextFields to return and the UITextView to return to it's original location.

I have achieved this using the following code.

```
func allDaySwitched() {
    if appointmentAllDayToggle.isOn {

        appointmentStartTimeTextfield.tag = 0
        appointmentStopTimeTextfield.tag = 0
        appointmentSummaryTextfield.tag = 4

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.appointmentStartTimeLabel.alpha = 0
            self.appointmentStopTimeLabel.alpha = 0
            self.appointmentStartTimeTextfield.alpha = 0
            self.appointmentStopTimeTextfield.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (true) in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame = CGRect(x: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.origin.x, y: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.origin.y - 50, width: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.width, height: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.height)


                self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.origin.x, y: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.origin.y - 50, width: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.width, height: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.height)


            }, completion: { (true) in

            })

        })


    } else {
        appointmentStartTimeTextfield.tag = 4
        appointmentStopTimeTextfield.tag = 5
        appointmentSummaryTextfield.tag = 6


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame = CGRect(x: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.origin.x, y: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.origin.y + 50, width: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.width, height: self.appointmentSummaryTextfield.frame.height)


            self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.origin.x, y: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.origin.y + 50, width: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.width, height: self.appointmentSummaryLabel.frame.height)

        }, completion: { (true) in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.appointmentStartTimeLabel.alpha = 1
                self.appointmentStopTimeLabel.alpha = 1
                self.appointmentStartTimeTextfield.alpha = 1
                self.appointmentStopTimeTextfield.alpha = 1

            }, completion: { (true) in

            })

        })

    }
}
```

This works perfectly, however, whenever the UITextView is focused it returns to it's original position. From there, if I toggle the UISwitch again it then moves further down the view.

How can I commit this change so that the UITextView doesn't move when focused? I have tried:

```
updateConstraints()
layoutIfNeeded()
setNeedsLayout()
```

In the animation completion event but none of them appear to commit the change?

How can I achieve this? - I have attached screenshots of behaviour

**Initial layout**

[image: Layout when loaded]

**Layout when toggled (desired)**

[image]

**Layout when Summary field focused (I have resigned the field in the photo to remove keyboard) - Not desired**

[image]

**Layout when Summary field focused and then the UISwitch togged - Not desired**

[image]

Comment: How are you building the view?
Are you using constraints?

Comment: @AatishMolasi  Yes I am 

`appointmentSummaryTextfield.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: appointmentSummaryLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        appointmentSummaryTextfield.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: appointmentContainerView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        appointmentSummaryTextfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true`

Comment: drag the `top constraints outlet` and `height outlet` of UITextView to the UIViewController and set it to 0 and after switch on again set it to desired constants.

Comment: All programmatic, no storyboard. 
I tried animating the constraints and although they animated on the initial toggle of the switch, when I switch back again, the summary field stayed where it was. I'll have another look though

Comment: in which method are you applying the constrains?

Comment: They are being applied in a layoutViews() method called from viewDidLoad()

Comment: Ah got it! I was animating the constraints slightly wrong before. re-did it and its working now. Thanks for your replies